# How to fire click event for choosing each plot in google map drawing manager function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, reactjs

I'm using google map javascript api to create labs for runner. I need to set marker icon for clicking each plot points. In this case i'm able to draw a line but can't able to set icon in each plots. How to achieve this? I'm struggling past one week to get this done.

```
const me = this;
    const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
      drawingControl: false,
      circleOptions: {
        fillColor: '#a8aaa9',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        clickable: false,
        editable: true,
        zIndex: 1,
      },
    });

    drawingManager.setMap(this.map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', OverlayCompleteEvent => {
      const bounds = OverlayCompleteEvent.overlay.getPath().getArray();
      me.setState({
        collectedCordinates: bounds,
      });
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'click', function(){
      // not firing here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From Google Maps API documentation:

> Note that google.maps.Map events, such as click and mousemove are disabled while drawing on the map.

[Drawing Layer(Library)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer#drawing_events)

If i got your goal correctly, you can try it by adding icon (in this example-Marker for each plot):

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', OverlayCompleteEvent => {
    const bounds = OverlayCompleteEvent.overlay.getPath().getArray();
    me.setState({
      collectedCordinates: bounds,
    });

    bounds.map((coord, i)=>{
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: coord.lat(), lng: coord.lng()},
        map: map,
        title: 'marker ' + i
      })
    });
  });
```